# get() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, django

Why am i getting this error? I am supposed to declare the author and article details at the same time but the django does not let me do that . Anybody knows how to solve this code problem?

```
class ArticleCreateView(CreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = ArticleCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def create(self, request):
        serializer_context = {
            'request': request
        }
        serializer_data = request.data.get('article','author',{})

        serializer = self.serializer_class(
        data=serializer_data, context=serializer_context
        )
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        response = {
            'success' : 'True',
            'status code' : status.HTTP_200_OK,
            'message': 'User registered successfully!',
            }
        status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Here is the problem

```
serializer_data = request.data.get('article','author',{})
TypeError: get() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
[10/May/2020 18:52:28] "POST /api/createpost/ HTTP/1.1" 500 98933
```

Other positional arguments are 2 arguments that are called "caption,details".

Update 1:*Serializer*

```
class ArticleCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    author = serializers.SerializerMethodField('_user')
    caption = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    details = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    def _user(self, obj):
        request = getattr(self.context, 'request', None)
        if request:
            return request.user.profile

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('id','author','caption','details')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        author = self.context.get('author', None)
        return author
        article = Post.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Post.objects.create(
            article = article,
            caption=post_data['caption'],
            details=post_data['details'],
           )
        return article
```

Comment: `request.data.get` is a function that accepts at most two parameters (the key, and a default value if it is missing), but you specify three values.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem what is the solution that i can use?Anything you know?

Comment: @UmarBeyoğlu can you share your serializers and the data you are passing? You should be able to pass nested data to the API and shouldn't need to manipulate the data

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i added the serializer part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing, data is a `dict`, you should remember that `get` method accepts only 2 arguments: key and default value if the key is not found.

Try changing that code onto this, if article is a `dict`:

```py
serialized_data = request.data.get('article', {}).get('author')
```

Otherwise, if article is a model object, try something like this:

```py
article = request.data.get('article', {})
if article:
    author = article.author
```

Comment: "non_field_errors": [
        "No data provided"
    ]
This is the error i get now. I think it is caused from data problem in serializers,not view. Right?

Comment: Yes, it means data is None somewhere. If you cannot ensure that data is always `not None`, add validation for this

Comment: i added the serializer part

Comment: i closed the discussion and i will move the new problem to a new question.Thank you!